# Excel 2010 Compare

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I know Excel 2013 has this function just automatically built to run a compare against another spreadsheet & I have 2013 at home, but my work using 2010.  Is there any VBA script which allows me to compare 2 worksheets that essentially look the same & highlights the differences?  Word 2010 has a similar kind of function.

Comment: If you can’t find one, consider saving both files as CSV or text and then doing a text file comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [the XL Comparator service](http://www.xlcomparator.net/).

It allows you to find lines in a first xls/xlsx file that are (or not) in a second file.
To make the comparison, it uses a reference column.